# Why Does This Function Segfault?

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

This has been troubling me for some time; this function doesn't even return, it just segfaults. I specify a correct file location, I check for errors at every possible point in the function, I don't understand?

```
GLchar* getShaderString(const GLchar* file_path){
    FILE* srcfile = NULL;
    if(!(srcfile = fopen(file_path, "r")))
        return(NULL);
    fseek(srcfile, 0l, SEEK_END);
    long len;
    if((len = ftell(srcfile)) == -1)
        return (NULL);
    fseek(srcfile, 0l, SEEK_SET);
    GLchar* buff;
    if(!(buff = malloc(len + 1)))
        return (NULL);
    fread((GLvoid*)buff, len, 1, srcfile);
    fclose(srcfile);
    buff[len + 1] = '\0';
    return (buff);
}
```

Comment: index is out of range in len+1.

Comment: Unrelated, but you also leak a `FILE` object by failing to call `fclose` if either the `fseek` or `malloc` fails.

Comment: A simple, basic rule of C's 0-indexing: given an array A of length N, access to A[N] is verboten (but you can take its address).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help other visitors to Stack Overflow in the future.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I posted this over a year ago, why is it still getting comments?

Comment: Because it got put in the close queue and got reviewed by people including me yesterday, and because I didn't accept the default reason (too broad) as the appropriate close reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fopen works on `const char*` not `const GLchar*`.

Also, `buff[len+1] = '\0';` should be `buff[len] = '\0';`.

Comment: `GLchar` is just a typedef for `char`, so that's fine by the compiler, but yeah, OP really ought to write `const char*` instead of `const GLchar*` here.

Comment: Is that an OpenGL specification or does it just happen to be? I'm not saying it's the issue, but it's possible OpenGL could change that to say support wide characters as it sees fit.

Comment: I'll accept this answer after the minimum time has passed. But yeah, it's an OpenGL typedef for char. And it doesn't matter if they change it, because this is OpenGL 3.1.

Comment: @CrazyCasta: The OpenGL specifies exact bit widths for the data types, so they don't necessarily correspond -- `GLchar` must be exactly 8 bits, according to §2.3.1 in the [Core Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec42.core.20120427.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

```
buff[len + 1] = '\0';
```

should be:

```
buff[len] = '\0';
```

You have `len + 1` elements in your array, your last element is at index `len`.